# Writing to a specific row in a csv, Python 3

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I currently have a list structured as:
**x=['a,b,c,d','e,f,g,h']**
And I would like to have each element (between '') to be written to separate rows and each comma separated value placed within a respective cell within that row.

Currently my code adds the full contents of the list 'x' to the top row and i dont know how to fix it.

Comment: What is your current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a generator comprehension (splitting each text of your list according to commas) as an argument to `csv.writerows` like this:

```
import csv

x=['a,b,c,d','e,f,g,h']

with open("output.csv","w",newline="") as f:
    cw = csv.writer(f)
    cw.writerows(l.split(",") for l in x)
```

Answer (score 0):

A short - and to be honest propably not the most beautiful - piece of code:

```
x=['a,b,c,d','e,f,g,h']
for ROWS in x:
    print("Handling row", ROWS)
    ROWS = str(ROWS)
    ROW_NEW = []
    if ROWS.count(",") > 0:
        for COLS in ROWS.split(","):
            ROW_NEW.append(COLS)
    print("Resulting row: " + str(ROW_NEW))
```

Instead of "print", you can use writerow() from the csv module (details here: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html)